# Why Visual Studio 2015 couldn't find iconv.h, a file dependency of libxml2?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, libxml2, iconv

I usually code in PHP, and new to Visual Studio and C, I followed the steps here — http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c14893/Libxml2-Everything-You-Need-in-an-XML-Library.htm and downloaded three files — libxml, iconv, zlib. It says, iconv and zlib are dependencies for libxml2.

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

static void print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node)
{
   xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

   for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
       if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
          printf("node type: Element, name: %s\n",
               cur_node->name);
       }
       print_element_names(cur_node->children);
   }
}

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

    if (argc != 2)  return(1);

    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION    // Macro to check API for match with
                             // the DLL we are using

    /*parse the file and get the DOM */
    if (doc = xmlReadFile("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", NULL, 0))     == NULL){
       printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", argv[1]);
       exit(-1);
       }

    /*Get the root element node */
    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    print_element_names(root_element);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);       // free document
    xmlCleanupParser();    // Free globals
    return 0;
    }
```

In my downloaded package, I have folders — iconv-1.9.2.win32, libxml2-2.7.8.win32, zlib-1.2.5.win32. [all these folders are lying side by side inside `workspace\libxml` folder]

I downloaded above from here — ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/

I entered the following path in Project Properties:

1. `Project > Properties > C/C++->General > Additional Include Directories` — `workspace\libxml\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\include`
2. `Project > Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories` — `workspace\libxml\iconv-1.9.2.win32\iconv-1.9.2.win32\include`

I have no idea where to put `zlib` folder path. (first question)
I built the solution in Visual Studio Professional 2015 (Windows 8, 64 bit) and got the following errors:

1. cannot open source file "iconv.h"
2. C1083    Cannot open include file: 'iconv.h': No such file or directory

GTK: I created: File > Project > VC++ > Empty Project

My questions are:

1. Where should I put, which specific path from all the three folders (from the downloaded package)?
2. I have to create standalone application, so I have to statically link the libxml2 Dll, am I going right?

Comment: Use `#include "file"` instead of `#include <file>`.  Never start with an empty project if you don't know the basics yet.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried what you suggested, that made no difference. The problem is not `#include` statements, the problem must be in `Project Properties` and its path, as it's not able to find the file `iconv.h` which lies in one of the files inside `#included` file

Comment: where is "iconv.h" located?  Try searching for it with Windows Search.  You will probably need to add this path "workspace\libxml\iconv-1.9.2.win32\iconv-1.9.2.win32\include", to your additional header files.  The additional libraries is where you put the paths to various *.lib files.

Comment: when setting up the search paths...  1) for the compiles, there will be 3 search paths, that each end in `include`.   2) for the libraries, there will be 3 search paths that each end in `lib`.    So the main problem is the paths to the *.h files needs to be expanded to have all three paths.  The paths to the libraries, needs to be expanded to have all three paths AND those paths needs to end at the directories that contain the libraries, not the directories that contain the header files.

Comment: @user3629249 I followed what you suggested and that worked. I never knew that we can set multiple paths. The mentioned errors have gone and now I have other new errors, but I'll take care of them. Thanks for the answer, you could have put this as answer, I'd have accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when setting up the search paths...

1) for the compiles, there will be 3 search paths, that each end in include.

2) for the libraries, there will be 3 search paths that each end in lib.

So the main problem is the paths to the *.h files needs to be expanded to have all three paths.

The paths to the libraries, needs to be expanded to have all three paths AND those paths needs to end at the directories that contain the libraries, not the directories that contain the header files.

Answer (score 0):

The (more internal) root cause of this issue likely is that
libxml2 very unfortunately currently has
iconv (or: icu) library as an openly visible **transitive dependency** of its **public interface** (here: encoding.h public interface header) definition. :(
(i.e., implementation details/specifics leaking out of a particular - not so well-defined? - interface)

Resulting in
all innocent consumers of libxml2 having to
have iconv / icu library config (include path / library search path / library / flags) provided (usually done automatically implicitly, via fully managed/inherited target-instance-based aggregation config, e.g. on CMake - as opposed to manually fumbled / overly static-syntax / non-functional thus weakly structured MSVS/msbuild craptastics), too.

And (once these extra configuration shenanigans have been successfully dealt with), to add insult to injury, one then
often ends up with an "Unused libraries:" diagnosis item (iconv.lib) - read: bloat / performance consequences - at libxml2 consumer side when using MSVC cl.exe /VERBOSE:UNUSEDLIBS diagnosis :(
(since consumers of libxml2 obviously often won't (need to) directly consume iconv themselves, too).

Not that all these details currently matter to someone who is currently painfully facing configuration fail fallout due to this API interfacing blunder :(

Comment: While you're mostly right, this doesn't answer the question.